# getting specific object in fetchedObjects without iteration

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app has a custom object `SSSchedule` that I persist in CoreData, with a `sortDescriptor` of `"date"` (`SSSchedule` has a variable `var date : NSDate?`).  Is there a more efficient method to finding a specific `SSSchedule` object with a specific `date` rather than iterating through the `fetchedObjects` array checking each for `schedule.date == myDate as! NSDate`?

My app references the `fetchedObjects` quite often, so I would imagine constantly mapping `fetchedObjects` to a dictionary of type `[String : SSSchedule]` (for example) every time the `context` is saved would affect performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a fetch request to return the objects matching that specific `date` from the datastore. If you are being consistent, then from what you've written you'll get back an array with one element.

Let Core Data do that searching for you. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a `plist` which has a Dictionary of Dictionaries. it could be a more what you need.

The first Dictionary will have a key of a tuple of (Day,Month,Year) which can be easily extracted from NSDate. and a value of a Dictionary which key is a tuple of (Hours, Minutes) also extracted from NSDate and a value of String which is the task to do at that time.

this way if you have a specific date, that date is the key to access only the tasks and events you have during that specific date in O(1) time complexity.
Now if you want to know if you have something at a specific time you access it in a similar way. The method is supposed to return String?. If there's a task at a specific time, it will return the task, otherwise it will return nil which means you're free at this time.

This is how the data structure should look `[(Day, Month,Year):[(Hours,Minutes):String]]`

Regarding extracting components from `NSDate`

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour |.CalendarUnitMinute 
|.CalendarUnitYear|.CalendarUnitMonth|.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: date)
let day = components.day
let month = components.month
let year = compononets.year    
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter() to build a new array with any objects that match your criteria:

```
let newArray = fetchedObjects.filter() { $0.date == myDate as! NSDate }
```

Then check the count of newArray and handle accordingly - unless you know the dates are unique, there could be zero, one or more elements in the array.